# Why is ng-click from ng-repeat having no effect on function?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

Trying to run a function in a clientside controller file using ng-click on a button in my HTML. Getting nothing and not sure why. All help appreciated.

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="CriminalsCtrl as criminals">
  <h1>Infamous Criminals</h1>
  <section>
    <ul id="criminals">
      <li ng-repeat="criminals in criminals.criminalArray">
        <strong>{{criminals.name}}</strong> <em>{{criminals.location}}</em> 
        <span class="status {{criminals.status}}">{{criminals.status}}</span>
        <button ng-click="criminals.criminalsDelete(criminal)" class="delete">X</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

CONTROLLER

```
  vm.criminalsDelete = criminalsDelete;

  function criminalsDelete(criminal) {
    console.log('ng-click');
    $http.delete(`http://localhost:4000/api/criminals/${criminal.id}`)
    .then(() => {
      const index = vm.criminalArray.indexOf(criminal);
      vm.criminalArray.splice(index, 1);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `criminals` name for the `controllerAs` syntax is being hidden by the `criminals` name for the `ng-repeat` iterator. Use something else for the iterator:

```
<body ng-controller="CriminalsCtrl as criminals">
  <h1>Infamous Criminals</h1>
  <section>
    <ul id="criminals">
      <li ng-repeat="perp ̶c̶r̶i̶m̶i̶n̶a̶l̶s̶ in criminals.criminalArray">
        <strong>{{perp.name}}</strong> <em>{{perp.location}}</em> 
        <span class="status {{perp.status}}">{{perp.status}}</span>
        <button ng-click="criminals.criminalsDelete(perp)" class="delete">X</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I would also rename id to something else as well just to avoid confusion. Nice catch!

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This form of code the controller for delete is best

```
     $scope.delete = function(index){
   $scope.Criminals.splice(index,1);
 }
```

I made a Complete CRUD for you for an example, you only have to put the http services.

See the snippet below.

```js
angular.module('App', []).controller('CrudCriminal', ['$scope',
 function($scope) {
   $scope.Criminals = [
       {
         name : "walter",
         location : "abq",
         status : "dead",
         editable : false
       },
       {
         name : "Jesse",
         location : "nebraska",
         status : "out",
         editable : false
       }
     ];
  
  $scope.entity = {}
     
  $scope.edit = function(index){
    $scope.entity = $scope.Criminals[index];
    $scope.entity.index = index;
    $scope.entity.editable = true;
  }
     
  $scope.delete = function(index){
    $scope.Criminals.splice(index,1);
  }
     
  $scope.save = function(index){
    $scope.Criminals[index].editable = false;
    
  }
     
  $scope.add = function(){
    $scope.Criminals.push({
       name : "",
        location : "",
        status : "",
        editable : true
    })
  }
 }
]);
```

```css
/* Styles go here */
body{
  margin:10px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-family:Arial;
}
table{
  border:1px solid #333;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%;
}
table tr td{
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:10px;
}
table tr td span{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="CrudCriminal">
       <h1>Infamous Criminals</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td><span ng-click="add()">Add New</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="criminal in Criminals">
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="criminal.name" ng-show="criminal.editable">
          <span ng-hide="criminal.editable">{{ criminal.name }}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="criminal.location" ng-show="criminal.editable">
          <span ng-hide="criminal.editable">{{ criminal.location }}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="criminal.status" ng-show="criminal.editable">
          <span ng-hide="criminal.editable">{{ criminal.status }}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span ng-click="edit($index)" ng-hide="criminal.editable">Edit</span>
          <span ng-click="save($index)" ng-show="criminal.editable">Save</span>
          <span ng-click="delete($index)"> | Delete</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```